# SQL - Sort a CSV field

Tags: sql, sorting, csv

I have a CSV field in my SQL server, which contains X-number of days.

Here's an example with numbers (to make it easier to read):

```
1,2,3,4
4,5,1,9
3,6,8,4
```

I would like to sort each line. Is there an easy way to do it?
I want to have following result:

```
1,2,3,4
1,4,5,9
3,4,6,8
```

Thanks!

Comment: "in my SQL server" - is this Microsoft SQLServer, or another RDBMS (Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc)? Will there be a fixed number of values (eg. always 4, as in the example) or could there be a variable number of values in a single CSV field?

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is not standard in the SQL language, nor is it readily available in SQL Server.

What you could do is write a User-Defined Function (UDF) in any .NET language, then call that function in your query. The function itself would simply take a string as input, expecting a CSV value, and return the sorted version of that string. You can then query your table with that function, like so:

```
SELECT SortedCsv(NumbersOfDays) FROM MyTable
```

You can find out more about writing UDF's in .NET (C#) in this article: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/19679-Creating-User-Defined-Function-Using-Managed-Code.aspx and this one: http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/09/06/hidden-gems-microsoft-sql-net-managed-code-support

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you use a programming language like python to read each line, sort it and optionally put it back into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @CSV TABLE(RID INT,ID INT,COL_NAME VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @CSV(RID,ID,COL_NAME)
 SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COL_NAME) AS RID
  ,ID,COL_NAME FROM
  (
    SELECT ID , Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS COL_NAME  
    FROM  
    (  
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COL_NAME) AS ID,  
     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(COL_NAME, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS COL_NAME
     FROM  TABLE_NAME
    ) AS A CROSS APPLY COL_NAME.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
  ) v


SELECT COL_NAME FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT  C1.ID,
  STUFF((SELECT ',' + C2.COL_NAME  AS [text()] FROM @CSV C2
         WHERE C2.ID = C1.ID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'' ) AS COL_NAME
  FROM @CSV C1
) RESULT
ORDER BY COL_NAME
```

Replace 'COL_NAME' and 'TABLE_NAME' with your column amd table names

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f10b/5)